# Problem storing data in MYSQL with PHP code run on Bitnami Lamp App using AWS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, bitnami

I’m testing a dynamic website using AWS with bitnami lamp app. Site written and tested locally with xampp . Locally works just fine.

I have a problem when storing information in database.

PHP code inserts ONE row in table one

`$pre_stmt->bind_param();
$pre_stmt->execute() or die($this->con->error);
$pre_stmt = $this->con->prepare;`

Works fine.

Then, mysql is supposed to returns key value and this is used to declare variable

`$invoice_no = $pre_stmt->insert_id`

Then insert several rows in a second table.

This works find when use locally. But when use  in http://awsboer.bitnamiapp.com/. No value is return with “$invoice_no = $pre_stmt->insert_id”.

This are errors. Fist line error when loading page, second when form is submited.

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFK3O.jpg)

Regards

Comment: The snippets of code you have shared are disjointed and in and of themelves seem unlikely to cause the error you describe. Without seeing the whole code you might struggle to get a meaningful answer

Comment: Kindly check the database column has the auto increment value

Comment: Also, http error 500 means that something went wrong on the server. You need to get the underlying error message, otherwise you will never know what went wrong.